# What Excel function allows sumproduct in a specific month while dividing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatables

I have the following table

| Total | Years | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $10,000 | 2 | 11/18/2023 |
| $20,000 | 4 | 11/19/2023 |
| $5,000 | 5 | 12/23/2023 |

I want the sum of the totals divided by the respective years if the date is in November. So the function should return $10,000 (10,000/2 + 20,000/4). How do I accomplish this?

I have tried `=IF(MONTH(C:C)="11",SUMPRODUCT(A:A,1/B:B),0)` but I got a spill function

Comment: You dont need an `IF()` as well as numbers shouldn't be within quotes/speech marks `""` as `MONTH()` function will be returning a number and not a text value, use of quotes are specifically made for Text Values.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way using `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT`

[image]

---

```
=SUM((MONTH(C2:C4)=11)*(A2:A4/B2:B4))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(C2:C4)=11)*(A2:A4/B2:B4))
```

Alternative approach though this is not needed, but still one could try:

```
=SUM(TOCOL(A2:A4/B2:B4/(MONTH(C2:C4)=11),2))
```

---

Comment: I believe you'd want the `SUMPRODUCT` with these parameters.  I think `SUM` may give a syntax error when you pass it logical conditions

Comment: Hi @JimmySmith thanks for your reply perhaps you can see the screenshot it does not return any error. If OP is not using `MS365` then they would need to hit the `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` or they can use `SUMPRODUCT()` They `SUM()` function is performing a `Boolean` Logic here which returns `True` --> `1` & `False` --> `0` and performs a sum like sumproduct here